# How do I create user account by chef-solo?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

### Question

1. How do I create user account by chef-solo?
2. Why does "users" recipe needs client.pem?

### Environment

- ruby is `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]`
- chef-solo is `Chef: 0.10.8`
- "users" recipe version is head at 2012-03-27 (commit:f6e1d421f3513c92a0cfbf89c77f750e402ba545).
- recipe only `{"run_list":["recipe[users::sysadmins]"]}`

### Description

I would create user account by chef-solo with recipe "[users](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users)".
But occurred error, following like this.

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
```

### Log

```
vagrant@lucid32:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
vagrant@lucid32:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1$ chef-solo -v
Chef: 0.10.8
vagrant@lucid32:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1$ cat /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/solo.rb
file_cache_path "/tmp/vagrant-chef-1"
cookbook_path ["/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks", "/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/cookbooks/cookbooks"]
role_path nil
log_level :debug
vagrant@lucid32:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1$ cat /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/dna.json
{"run_list":["recipe[users::sysadmins]"]}
vagrant@lucid32:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1$ sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j dna.json
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:48 -0700] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.8 ***
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Building node object for lucid32
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[users::sysadmins]"] from JSON
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Platform is ubuntu version 10.04
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Run List is [recipe[users::sysadmins]]
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Run List expands to [users::sysadmins]
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid32
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Running start handlers
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: No chefignore file found at /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/chefignore no files will be ignored
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: No chefignore file found at /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/cookbooks/cookbooks/chefignore no files will be ignored
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loading cookbook users's providers from /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb into a provider named users_manage defined in Chef::Provider::UsersManage
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loading cookbook users's resources from /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/resources/manage.rb
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/resources/manage.rb into a resource named users_manage defined in Chef::Resource::UsersManage
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loading Recipe users::sysadmins via include_recipe
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Found recipe sysadmins in cookbook users
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Loading from cookbook_path: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks, /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/cookbooks/cookbooks
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Converging node lucid32
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Processing users_manage[sysadmin] on lucid32
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] INFO: Processing users_manage[sysadmin] action remove (users::sysadmins line 23)
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /etc/chef/client.pem>
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] ERROR: users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) has had an error
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] ERROR: users_manage[sysadmin] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/recipes/sysadmins.rb:23:in `from_file') had an error:
users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:62:in `load_signing_key'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:33:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `search'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb:27:in `class_from_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `instance_eval'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `action_remove'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `run_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:45:in `run_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:76:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:312:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:160:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/chef-solo:25
/opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing - users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:62:in `load_signing_key'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:33:in `initialize'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `new'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `initialize'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `new'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `initialize'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `new'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `search'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb:27:in `class_from_file'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `action_remove'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `send'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `run_action'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:45:in `run_action'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:76:in `converge'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:312:in `converge'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:160:in `run'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `run_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/chef-solo:25
  /opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19:in `load'
  /opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] DEBUG: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:62:in `load_signing_key'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:33:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/rest.rb:47:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `initialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `new'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language.rb:133:in `search'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/users/providers/manage.rb:27:in `class_from_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `instance_eval'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:104:in `action_remove'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `run_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:45:in `run_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:76:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:312:in `converge'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:160:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/chef-solo:25
/opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby/bin//chef-solo:19
[Mon, 26 Mar 2012 17:54:49 -0700] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: users_manage[sysadmin] (users::sysadmins line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
```

Comment: Are you using other recipies in your run-list?

Remember, if you're doing a chef-solo run, you have to download all the cookbooks locally, then run `chef-solo`

Comment: No, I use "users" recipe only.
dna.json is `{"run_list":["recipe[users::sysadmins]"]}`.

Comment: Right.  

From the documentation on the github project, it looks like you might need to create some users first though: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users

It looks like the error is coming from missing elements from the user databags described in the link above:
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users/blob/master/providers/manage.rb#L27

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Opscode's "users" cookbook relies on using server centric features for user management, namely data bags and search. It is not designed or intended to work with Chef Solo.

The `users_manage` resource that is used in the `users::sysadmins` recipe runs a Chef Search query against the `users` data bag. When the recipe runs, it attempts to connect to a server, which is why it is looking for `/etc/chef/client.pem` - to authenticate with a Chef Server. Since you have neither, it fails.

*Update*

There is now a cookbook that adds "search-like" functionality for data bag items to Chef Solo that may be of interest for using the "users" cookbook.

- [Chef Solo Search cookbook](https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search)

Note that the "users" cookbook [currently](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users/commit/22e5fdf8e9d5215847fd66757a1f7d1e5c3d60f6) checks for Chef Solo and will not run if detected. This is part of an effort recently to pass linting check from foodcritic, per [FC003](http://acrmp.github.com/foodcritic/#FC003). Version [1.1.2 of the users cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/users) does not include this change (it **is** in the [master branch](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users/))

Answer (score 15):

Finally I succeeded in creating an account with chef-solo and data_bags.

It needs:

- [chef-solo-search](https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search)
- [users](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users/tree/9aaaddc230e80ce280409fe092f669c45b19e7ac)(require version 1.1.2, **not working at head revision**)

cookbooks.

See https://github.com/niku/vagrant_config_files/tree/minimum_set

Comment: Just trying to get the options. If I want a user in a data bag I use this. If I want to create a user by coding a resource I would have to use something else.

Comment: This only works for users in the `sysadmins' group.  If you want to create any users look at Anton Orel's answer.

Answer (score 11):

It would be better to use [this cookbook](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-user).It gives more flexible user resource.
For example:

```
user_account 'hsolo' do
  comment   'Han Solo'
  # keys for file ~/.ssh/authorized keys
  ssh_keys  ['3dc348d9af8027df7b9c...', '2154d3734d609eb5c452...']
end
```

User's ssh keys and the other prefs will be gerenated automatically.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [user resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-User) to create a local user, for example:

```
user "random" do
  comment "Random User"
  uid 1000
  gid "users"
  home "/home/random"
  shell "/bin/zsh"
  password "$1$JJsvHslV$szsCjVEroftprNn4JHtDi."
end
```

Comment: [Doesn't seem to be a documented option to add SSH keys via the user resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html). Most companies would want ssh keys or the option to use them. If I understand this correctly (the seeming redundancy of user creation in Chef makes me scratch my head often), I think usage of this resource should be discouraged and deprecated.